# std::for_each usage -> capturing variables

Tags: c++, foreach, stl

```
      void reset(const std::string& a, const std::string& b) const
  {
   std::for_each(this->begin(), this->end(), [&](const std::string& a, const std::string& b, ClassA* cv)
           {
        if( cv->getA == a && cv->getb == b)
            cv->reset();
           });

  }
```

Is there a simple way to compare member function of ClassA with a and b with for_each? What's other best solution?

Comment: Make it `[&](ClassA* cv){ ... }`. `a` and `b` are captured, not passed in as parameters. This assumes `this->begin()` and `this->end()` are iterators into a container of `ClassA*`

Answer (score 1):

Make it `[&](ClassA* cv){ ... }`. The parameters `a` and `b` are captured by your `[&]` and are available inside the lambda (they are not passed as arguments).

You could also use:

```
void reset(const std::string& a, const std::string& b) const {
    for (auto cv : *this)
        if(cv->getA == a && cv->getb == b)
            cv->reset();
}
```

Which looks a little bit cleaner.